# How do I apply #[must_use] to an async function?

Tags: rust

`#[must_use]` seems to have no effect on async functions. This code generates no warnings:

```
#[must_use]
async fn launch_missiles() -> u32 {
    42
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    launch_missiles().await;
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=729fa4e6ddfd25f649308c776e0c6e57))

Is this expected behavior, or is it a language design flaw / compiler bug?

If it's expected, what are my alternatives? It works fine if the return type is `#[must_use]` so I've started creating a `MustUse<_>` wrapper type. It seems like overkill, though. Am I missing a simpler workaround?

Comment: Well, [it does have an effect](https://gist.github.com/bc9bafc67b5f7d248b13042fec241176): You get the warning if you remove the `.await`. It's just not the expected effect.

Comment: @mcarton as Future already have must use it's print two time XD

Comment: Weirdly enough, I can't find anything on the issue tracker about this. (Clearly `#[must_use]` is useless on `async` at the moment).

Comment: @Stargateur sources of those warnings are different, this implementation is roughly the same : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0ffd00ffae6603f632a2c222f8738cb6 , First one says you need to use the `Future`, in my case it is `X`, second one says you need to use the result of `fn`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can currently do (without manually implementing what `async` is doing) is to return a `#[must_use]` wrapper type:

```rust
#[must_use]
struct MustUse<T : ?Sized>(T);

#[must_use]
async fn launch_missiles() -> MustUse<u32> {
    MustUse(42)
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    launch_missiles().await;
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fc4f14be47d373f82cebd3665a41c9a9)</sup>